# Add jpg file names to a list box and select one for watching - Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

How can read a selected jpg from this list box and view it in an axes?

```
    function selectFolderButtonPushed(app, event)
        app.selectedPath = uigetdir();
        jpgFileInfo = dir(fullfile(app.selectedPath, '*.jpg'));
        app.jpgListBox.Items =  {jpgFileInfo.name}';
    end


    function loadimageButtonPushed(app, event)
        imageSelected = imread(......);
        imshow(imageSelected, app.imageAxes);
    end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope it helps:

```
function SelectFolderButtonPushed(app, event)
            app.selectedPath = uigetdir();
            jpgFileInfo = dir(fullfile(app.selectedPath, '*.jpg')) 
            app.jpgListBox.Items =  {jpgFileInfo.name}'; 
        end
 
        function loadimageButtonPushed(app, event)
            selectedFileName = app.jpgListBox.Value;
            selectedPath = app.selectedPath;
            imageSelected =strcat(selectedPath, "\", selectedFileName)
            imshow(imageSelected,'Parent',app.imageAxes); 
        end
```